# Tracking when/why datasets are removed from Quandl

Tags: fama-french, quandl

While exploring [this blogpost](http://www.business-science.io/code-tools/2017/03/19/tidyquant-quandl-integration.html) on the Tidyquant library for R, I noticed a Fama French dataset on Quandl (dataset: `KFRENCH`). This no longer (circa July 2018) seems to be available on Quandl and I can find no references as to when or why it was removed.

Is there info on what happened to the KFRENCH dataset? The factors are available directly from Ken French's Datmouth site at http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html. I'm hoping this wasn't a copyright issue of some sort. In general, is there a way to track when datasets are added to or removed from Quandl apart from the official Quandl blog?